# How to integrate spring boot + react CSRF

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I have added the below code in spring security

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

But on react side when I am. trying to react read `cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')` it is giving undefined.

Can anyone help !!.

Also, How do spring send back the XSRF token to react.

Comment: Your `csrfTokenRepository` configuration looks correct. So next, is the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie present? Check in Chrome dev tools with F12  > Application tab > Cookies on left > your domain. And see if it's listed there.

Comment: @drumonii  thanks for reply, but i dont see XSRF-Token in application tab .However when i checked the network tab and  then in response header I see Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=dasdasd; Path=/; Secure but in cookies nothing is present .Can you please help.

Comment: That's good, the response header is setting the cookie correctly. Are there any HttpOnly cookies on your domain? All I think of is that something is overriding your cookie or all cookies to be HttpOnly, perhaps your application server?

Comment: @drumonii . I dont have any http only cookie. Also my webserver and application server is running on different ports . Would that make any difference ?

Comment: No, different ports shouldn't matter. But what about different domains? You can't read cookies from another domain.

Comment: @drumonii. Domains are same.